# Datastax: CorruptSSTableException in the debug log file

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We are getting following exception in the debug log under '/var/log/cassandra'

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: Corrupted: /var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace/table-name-10c4a6813cc011e7bb285ba6dc91a4cc/mc-3600-big-Data.db
```

We perform nodetool repair daily on one node. And after crash started to occur more often we performed full nodetool repair couple of times, but it didn't help for long.

We are running on DSE 5.0.7. 
Can you please help us how can we address this.